# Error when injecting a service or factory in config block

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i'm trying to make a blog using angular 1.6, all works fine except when i created a service and inject into config file. Test directive works fine, only breaks when inject myService service/factory.

app.coffee

```
app = angular.module 'dts',['ngRoute']

app.service 'myService', ->
    this.asd = ""

app.directive 'ngHello', ->
    return {
        restrict:'E'
        replace: true
        template: "<h1>Hola mundo</h1>"
        link: (scope,element,attrs)->

    }
```

config.coffee

```
app = angular.module 'dts'

app.config ["$locationProvider","$routeProvider","myService", ($locationProvider,$routeProvider,myService)->

    $routeProvider

        .when "/",
            controller: "mainCtrl"
            templateUrl: "/app/views/index.html"

        .when "/blog",
            controller: "blogCtrl"
            templateUrl: "/app/views/blog/index.html"

        .when "/blog/post/:id",
            controller: "blogCtrl"
            templateUrl: "/app/views/blog/single.html"

        .when "/contact",
            controller: "contactCtrl"
            templateUrl: "/app/views/contact.html"

        .otherwise '/'



    $locationProvider.html5Mode
        enabled: true
        requireBase: false
]
```

script includes

```
script(src="/js/libs/angular.min.js")
script(src="/app/modules/angular-route.min.js")
script(src="/app/app.js")
script(src="/app/services/slugs.js")
script(src="/app/config.js")
script(src="/app/controllers/main.js")
script(src="/app/controllers/blog.js")
```

What i'm doing wrong?

I searched about problems or deprecating about service or factory on 1.6 version, but i can't find nothing. I downgrade angular to 1.5.6 and does not works too.

I tried to move service/factory to app file, but breaks too (before i create it on services.js)

Comment: Why are you trying to inject service in config ?

Comment: I want to make routes. I have a list of routes in database to create slugs like :

blog/post/1 -> blog/post/lorem-ipsum-dolor

What's the best way to do this?

Comment: That is not very clear or specific

Comment: i have an array of post slugs on db, the current url to view posts is /blog/post/1 and i want to use /blog/post/name-of-post without pass name as param.

In laravel or codeigniter i create database routes and use a foreach on routes.

I'm trying to do the same with angular routes:

[1] /blog/post/1 /blog/post/lorem-ipsum
[2] /blog/post/2 /blog/post/lalalala
etc.

Comment: Use a route `resolve` and inject service in that

Comment: Thank you very much @charlietfl.

Answer (score 1):

you have to inject `myServiceProvider` in config , you cannot inject service in config function

Comment: Thanks, in some past examples i use the name of service and it works good, but i never tried to use in config, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From the Docs:

> ## Module Loading & Dependencies
>
> - **Configuration blocks** - get executed during the provider registrations and configuration phase. **Only providers and constants can be injected into configuration blocks.** This is to prevent accidental instantiation of services before they have been fully configured.
>
> [— AngularJS Developer Guide - Modules (Loading & Dependencies)](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module#module-loading-dependencies)

Route tables can not be created or changed by services.

On the other hand, services are injectable in the resolve functions of a route table as those functions are invoked during the run phase of an application.